# Azure pipeline CopyFiles with wildcard filename

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This works

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  condition: eq(variables.publishDeployables, true)
  displayName: 'Add README.md to output'
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: 'README.MD'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

But this:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  condition: eq(variables.publishDeployables, true)
  displayName: 'Add SQL to output'
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: 'Setup*.sql'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

- takes ages searching through all subdirectories, and
- matched `SetupSecurity.sql` but does not match `Setup.sql`.

What's going on?!

**Update: log output**

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Add SQL to output'
##[debug]Evaluating: eq(variables['publishDeployables'], True)
##[debug]Evaluating eq:
##[debug]..Evaluating indexer:
##[debug]....Evaluating variables:
##[debug]....=> Object
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'publishDeployables'
##[debug]..=> 'True'
##[debug]..Evaluating Boolean:
##[debug]..=> True
##[debug]..=> 'True'
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Expanded: eq('True', True)
##[debug]Result: True
##[section]Starting: Add SQL to output
==============================================================================
Task         : Copy files
Description  : Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
Version      : 2.151.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files
==============================================================================
##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\agent\_work
##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_CLEANTARGETFOLDER
##[debug]loading INPUT_CONTENTS
##[debug]loading INPUT_FLATTENFOLDERS
##[debug]loading INPUT_OVERWRITE
##[debug]loading INPUT_PRESERVETIMESTAMP
##[debug]loading INPUT_SOURCEFOLDER
##[debug]loading INPUT_TARGETFOLDER
##[debug]loading SECRET_CHECKMARX_PASSWORD
##[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loaded 12
##[debug]check path : C:\agent\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.151.1\task.json
##[debug]set resource file to: C:\agent\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.151.1\task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]Contents=Setup*.sql
##[debug]SourceFolder=C:\agent\_work\12\s
##[debug]check path : C:\agent\_work\12\s
##[debug]TargetFolder=C:\agent\_work\12\a
##[debug]CleanTargetFolder=false
##[debug]OverWrite=false
##[debug]flattenFolders=false
##[debug]preserveTimestamp=false
##[debug]findPath: 'C:\agent\_work\12\s'
##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s (directory)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git (directory)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git\config (file)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git\description (file)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git\FETCH_HEAD (file)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git\HEAD (file)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git\hooks (directory)
##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\12\s\.git\hooks\applypatch-msg.sample (file)
...
```

Why is the copy thing descending into subdirectories that I'm not interested in?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but am guessing: `**/Setup*.sql`

Comment: The files I want are in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`; I don't want `**` becase I don't want to waste time searching through subdirectories. The files are `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Setup*.sql`

Answer (score 0):

> Azure pipeline CopyFiles with wildcard filename

If you do not want to waste time searching through subdirectories, you could exclude the subdirectories with `!**\TestSubfolder\Setup*.sql`:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  condition: eq(variables.publishDeployables, true)
  displayName: 'Add SQL to output'
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     Setup*.sql
     !**\TestSubfolder\Setup*.sql
     !**\TestSubfolder2\Setup*.sql
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

And as I test, `Setup*.sql` match the file `Setup.sql`, if it not work for you, you may need to check the path of the file `Setup.sql`：

[image]

Comment: But why is it searching subfolders when my pattern _doesn't_ contain `**`?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough, This is the expected behavior because you specify the source folder to be $(Build.SourcesDirectory), then the copy task will list all the files under the folder before matching Contents to match the Contents we set.

Comment: The documentation implies that only the `sourceFolder` is searched for files; it does not say that all subfolders are also searched. This is counterintuitive because searchign all subfolders is different to the familiar behaviour of, say, `ls` and `dir`.

Comment: How can I exclude folders whose names match `Foo*`? (`!Foo*\**` doesn't work.)

Comment: Hang on, the documentation says: _`*` copies all files in the specified source folder_. So it shouldn't be looking in subfolders.